# Animate the scale of an image from 100vh to 100% width

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am trying to animate the scaling of an image. i have set the first instance like this:

```
section.workimage .image.fit img{
  height: calc(100vh - 5rem);
}
```

with a click i change the class to that:

```
section.workimage .image.fat img{
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

and here i wanted to create the transition:

```
section.workimage .image img{
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  width: auto;
}
```

unfortunately that doesn't work, since i change from a height based limitation to a width based. 
does anyone have an idea how to smoothly animate this? right now it just jumps.

thanks!

i have created an example fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/possible/d067634v/

Comment: Do you only need it to increase in size, or do you also need it to decrease in size?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some trick using max-height propery :

```
section.workimage .image.fit img{
  height: calc(100vh - 5rem);
  max-height: calc(100vh);
}

section.workimage .image.fat img{
  height: auto;
  max-height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
}

section.workimage .image img{
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  width: auto;
}
```

Look here : https://jsfiddle.net/aLtn2nf2/

Comment: Thanks Vincent, this unfortunately leads to a weird jumpy animation, that looks more like a squeeze than a scale...

Comment: Yes true.. To be honest, I don't think you can do it with pure CSS. Check using Javascript.